# Unable to change datatype of columns while import CSV to SQL in R

Tags: r, sqldatatypes, dbi, rpostgres

I have a csv file. I need to import it in SQL. But while importing I need to change the names of columns and I want to change the datatype for all the columns. Csv columns are little weird. Few examples are:

```
City, special label
City label
Year/Month start
Lis of city
```

I am trying following code in R. It is able to change column names but not datatype of columns. After being imported in SQL, the column shows datatypes which I need to change. e.g. col 1,2,3,4 shows datatype txt but i want to change it to varchar, col 5,6 shows datatype double precision but I want to chaneg it to real, col 7, 8 shows datatype txt whereas it is date, i want to change it to date. Could anyone please help.

Code:

```
library(RPostgres)
library(DBI)

#Establish R & PostgreSQL Connection using RPostgres
dsn_database = "..."   # Specify the name of your Database
dsn_hostname = "...."  # Specify host name 
dsn_port = "5432"                # Specify your port number. e.g. 98939
dsn_uid = "...."         # Specify your username. e.g. "admin"
dsn_pwd = "..."        # Specify your password. e.g. "xxx"


tryCatch({
  drv <- dbDriver("Postgres")
  print("Connecting to Database…")
  connec <- dbConnect(drv, 
                      dbname = dsn_database,
                      host = dsn_hostname, 
                      port = dsn_port,
                      user = dsn_uid, 
                      password = dsn_pwd)
  print("Database Connected!")
},
error=function(cond) {
  print("Unable to connect to Database.")
})


csv_file <- "D:/Data/new.csv"
csv_data_frame <- read.csv(csv_file)

# Specify the new column names here as they should appear in the PostgreSQL table
new_column_names <- c("city_name", "city_id", "location", "city_info", "latitude", "longitude", "height_of_city_above_sea_level", "date_start", "date_end", "comment", "lis")
colnames(csv_data_frame) <- new_column_names

csv_data_frame$city_name <- as.character(csv_data_frame$city_name)
csv_data_frame$city_id <- as.character(csv_data_frame$city_id)
..
..                  (#performed it for all columns)

table_name <- "xyz"
column_names <- new_column_names
column_types <- c("varchar(50)", "char(3)", "varchar(50)", "varchar(200)", "real", "real", "real", "date", "date", "varchar(1000)", "varchar(500)")

create_table_query <- paste0(
  "CREATE TABLE ", table_name, " (",
  paste(paste(column_names, column_types, sep = " "), collapse = ", "),
  ");"
)

dbExecute(connec, create_table_query)

DBI::dbWriteTable(connec, table_name, csv_data_frame, overwrite = TRUE)
```

Could anyone please help me how to resolve it and obtain the desired goal

Comment: The use of `overwrite=TRUE` is (I believe) dropping and recreating the table. I suggest `dbWriteTable(..., create=FALSE, overwrite=FALSE)`, optionally `append=TRUE` in there as well. Since you _just_ created it, you should not need to delete any rows first.